# How can I use datetime.strptime on a string in the format '0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00'?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Due to my application's circumstances, I would prefer to use `datetime.strptime` instead of `dateutil.parser`.

After looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), I thought that `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z` may be the proper format for parsing a date string like this. Yet it still gives me an error.

#### Example

```py
from datetime import datetime

d = '0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00'
datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

```
ValueError: time data '0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00' does not 
            match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: `0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00` is an invalid value. There's no date 0. Have you tried to use a valid date string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Even with a valid string `%z` doesn't match the `HH:mm` format for offsets. The answers to the duplicate question show the alternatives, including `datetime.fromisoformat` in Python 3.7+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with timezones is to use `dateutil.parser`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
date_obj = parse('1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00')

date_obj

> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

But you have to pass a valid datetime-value (not only zeros...)

If you want to use `strptime()`, the timezone has to be in the format `0000` not `00:00`, so this works:

```
d = '1900-02-05T11:43:32+0000'
datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

> datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 5, 11, 43, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your second block implementation using `strptime` is just what I was looking for. I will modify the date string's offset to omit the colon at the end of the string and then pass the modified version to `strptime`.

Answer (score 1):

Very late reply but for posterity, if you really want to parse it with `strptime` you can use `%z`

https://intellipaat.com/community/58366/the-strptime-example-for-datetime-with-tz-offset

Example:

```
datetime_string = "2021-01-01T10:25:00+00:00"
obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(repr(obj))
>>> datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

datetime_string = datetime.strftime(obj, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(datetime_string)
>>> 2021-01-01T10:25:00+0000
```

although notice the offset is now shown as `+0000` which may be enough for you.

if you still insist on the output being the ISO 8601 format, and insist on using `strftime` to bring the format back to +00:00, you have to use a custom `tzinfo` object.

Example:

```
class TZ1(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt): return timedelta(hours=0)
    def dst(self, dt):  return timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self, dt): return "+00:00"

datetime_string = "2021-01-01T10:25:00+00:00"
obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").replace(tzinfo=TZ1())
>>> datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 10, 25, tzinfo=<__main__.TZ1 object at 0x7ff6e1c41f50>)

datetime_string = datetime.strftime(obj, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
print(datetime_string)
>>> 2021-01-01T10:25:00+00:00
```

This example is obviously hardcoded for UTC+0, but you can apply some logic based on the `dt` argument if necessary.

This approach can be quite useful (as opposed to the magic in the `dateutil` library) if you are setting up strict rules for dates and times in data processing from untrustworthy sources, to be used with validation, coercion etc. as you can set rigid inputs and outputs.

Comment: update: dateutil provides a `tzoffset` function to build this for you so you don't have to declare a class.  example: `dt.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(name="+00:00", offset=0))` source: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzoffset

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your code but the error is not given because of the wrong format but because `'0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00'` is not a valid time, because zero is no date. If you try it with another time like: `'1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'` it should work just fine.

Comment: What do you mean with the standard offset format? The code seems to be running fine for me with my changes.